# How can i change all code from one file where string equals to string in another file in python. I will explain in example

Tags: python, split, python-3.7

I have file **a.txt** and inside is:*aaa = bbb, ccc = ddd, eee = fff,*. And i have multiply files(**b.txt,c.txt**...) that are similar to:*aaa = ggg, asd = fsd, eee = hhh,*. I want to create new file **combine.txt** that will try to find same strings before **"="** sign and replace them with data from another file after **"="** sign. So if we look exaples up,  the new file (**combine.txt**) would look like:*aaa = ddd, asd = fsd, eee = fff,* I was trying to do that with split() method(maybe there is better way:D), but im new in to programming so i need help :)

```
file1 = open("/home/xxx/Desktop/Input1").read().split(" = ")

for line in a:

Type =  line.split(" = ")
a1 = Type[0]
c = Type[1]

file2 = [open("/home/xxx/Desktop/Input2").read()];

for line in file2:
Type =  line.split(" = ")
a2= Type[0]
d = Type[1]

output = open("/home/xxx/Desktop/Output1").write();

if(a1 == a2):
print(a1 + ' = ' + d)
```

Comment: Did my answer below work?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your text files only contain lines of assignments of the form aaa=bbb, you could, for instance, read the assignments into dictionaries and combine them like this:

```
def dict_from_file(filename):   
    dict_file = {}
    with open(filename) as file1:
        for l in file1:
            arr=l.split("=")
            dict_file[arr[0].strip()] = arr[1].strip()
    return dict_file
file1_dict = dict_from_file("your_first_file.txt")
file2_dict = dict_from_file("your_second_file.txt")

print({**file1_dict, **file2_dict})
```

The last line overwrites values from the first file with those of the second. If you need more complicated substitutions, you can perform them in further processing steps based on the keys in the dictionaries. You can obviously extend this to more than two files if needed.

Comment: @joe this solution also works and is neater than my suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you'd like to replace the values of Input1, with the values of Input 2? if so the below will work for you:

```
def dict_from_file(filename):   
    dict_file = {}
    with open(filename) as file1:
        for l in file1:
            arr=l.split("=")
            dict_file[arr[0].strip()] = arr[1].strip()
    return dict_file

file1_dict = dict_from_file("Input1.txt")
file2_dict = dict_from_file("Input2.txt")

output_file = open("output.txt", 'w')
output_file.write("\n".join([f'{k} = {v}' for k,v in {**file1_dict, **file2_dict}.items()]))
```

Comment: Actually its not working :D I explained all in first post, if you have time for checking it out :)

Comment: Well, still not. But Im working on it. After Im done, I will post my solution here. Thank you a lot :)

Comment: I've modified @ctenar answer to write your output file, this will work as long as you add the files that you want to work on as necessary.